# Add capability for editors to modify custom fields

Tags: custom-field, capabilities

Editors don't have a way to edit custom fields and I'm not seeing the capability in the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Is there a way to give access to that without making a user an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a special capability. When editing a post the editor just need to click on the tab "option" in the upper right corner and check the box for visibility of custom fields.

Comment: Thanks I was removing that option in my functions.php file.